# Powershell [Azure.] Namespace missing

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to play around with Powershell and Azure KeyVault.
As some tasks can't be done with the 'native' Azure PS commands, e.g creating JsonWebKeys, so I installed:

```
Register-PackageSource -Name MyNuGet -Location https://www.nuget.org/api/v2 -ProviderName NuGet
Install-Package  Azure.Security.KeyVault.keys -skipdependencies
```

I was hoping I could use now s.th like

```
$jwk=[azure.security.keyvault.keys]::jsonwebkey($myRSAKey)
```

however there still is no [Azure.xxx] Namespace at all on my system.
What did I miss?

Comment: `Keys` is not a type, `Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys` _is_ the namespace

Comment: Please use `[.Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys.JsonWebKey ]:: new($myRSAKey)` to create a class. Besides, could you please tell me why not use Azure PowerShell to create key vault key?

Comment: Jim, I don't want to create a class, esp since MS is already offering one with the same name. Key has to be created locally, then transfered to Azure not within Azure KeyVault itself.

Answer (score 0):

@Jim Xu
As the OP wrote initially it is not possible with Azure Powershell as this is not available in Azure Powershell. 
Might be he is wrong, then would be good if you can give some hints or examples.